# Run storybookJS from npm scripts for nested project

Tags: npm, storybook, npm-scripts

I moved all scripts from all nested package.json to the parent project.
Everything works fine except the storybook tests.
Storybook was installed in a nested project and I want to keep all dependencies where they belong.
When I try, however, to start storybook from the parent it can’t find the script ‚start-storybook‘.

The scripts-section of the nested project looks like this:

```
"scripts":{

 "storybook":"start-storybook -p 6006 —no-open"
}
```

In the parent I tried to

```
cd nested-project-dir
```

and

```
—prefix
```

the npm task but neither way it worked. Any ideas on this matter?